Can anyone please just give me tge answer. I just want to crosscheck
A university pharmacy department has two cell culture laboratories which it hires out by the day. Ths number of demands per day may be modelled by a Poisson distribution with mean 2. In a period 100 working days, how many times do you expect a) neither laboratory to be used? b) some requests for a laboratory to have to be refused/

What answers did you get?

A) 13.53 days B)32.33 days

Could you also show the work that led you to those answers?  It's not immediately obvious how we can answer the second question without knowing the labs' maximum capacities? (Or is the assumption that each lab can only handle one demand per day?)
